# Solution passes 37 test cases out of 39 but says 'Time Limit exceeded' for the rest

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I wrote the following piece of code about 'Maximum depth of binary tree'. Its a recursive solution. I was provided with the following template which had to be used :

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
```

Given this template, here goes my code :

```
class Solution(object):
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """        
        if(not root):
            return 0
        return self.findDepth(root,1)  #self-defined function passing node and depth
        
    def findDepth(self,node,depth):
        
        if(node):
            '''if(node.left and not node.right):
            node=node.left
            if(node.right and not node.left):
            node=node.right'''
            if(node.left or node.right):
                depth=depth+1
            depth=self.findDepth(node.left,depth) if self.findDepth(node.left,depth)>self.findDepth(node.right,depth) else self.findDepth(node.right,depth)  #recursion after computing depth every time
        return depth
```

The solution works fine with 37 test cases but for the remaining I get an error from 'Time Limit exceeded'. I googled and learnt that it happens because the code isn't properly optimized or has some unnecessary loops/lists/data structures. I haven't used any unused data structure and code is optimized as much possible. How to get rid of the error message so that the code may try out the remaining test cases within time limit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code is in two chunks and has no driver.
Don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that highlights the problem.

Comment: Note that you're basically asking for a code review here -- which is a different site, StackExchange.CodeReview.  However, a simple trace of calls might be within Stack Overflow's charter.  Complete your MRE.  Insert some basic diagnosis, such as counting function calls -- you should have *one* call per node in the tree.  Then you have a *specific* question, and we can work on your problem.  As it stands, you're leaving us to eye-check your code -- as the posting guidelines tell you, "Make it easy for others to help you."

Comment: Store your recursive call result in a variable. You're traversing both subtrees twice for every node. That's a _lot_ of extra work. This ternary is one too clever.

Answer (score 1):

> code is optimized as much possible

Far from it, you call `self.findDepth(...)` twice as often as necessary.  Also, you force one final recursion that you *know* is going to fail just to return the `depth` argument -- an `if` is cheaper than a method invocation.  I'd expect something more like (warning, untested code):

```
class Solution():
    def maxDepth(self, node):
        """
        :type node: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """

        depth = 0

        if node:
            left_depth = self.maxDepth(node.left) if node.left else 0
            right_depth = self.maxDepth(node.right) if node.right else 0

            depth = 1 + max(left_depth, right_depth)

        return depth
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. One question, can you please explain where is the call getting executed twice as many times necessary in my code? And how is that prevented in your solution?

Comment: @QUEEN, as others have noted, the problem is this statement `depth=self.findDepth(node.left,depth) if self.findDepth(node.left,depth)>self.findDepth(node.right,depth) else self.findDepth(node.right,depth)` where the result of `self.findDepth(node.left,depth)` (and ditto "right") should have been saved in a local variable rather than invoking the call again (again, ditto "right").  My solution uses local variables to avoid the duplicate calls.

Comment: I actually didn't understand how the recursion is working inside. Can someone please explain the recursion stack inside and how the variable values are changing accordingly?